# php mysql sum row total

Tags: php, mysql

i use below php to search mysql database and it's working so far, below is the sample output mysql database displayed in webpage, what's next i am trying to do a sum total for column 'act', this sound easy but i am still struggling how to do this, anyone can enlighten me pls?

[image]

```
<?php

$query10 = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE amr_id =" . $searchkey;
        $result10 = $conn->query($query10);
                           
        if ($result10->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table id='customers'  border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' style='text-align:left;'><tr><th>Date</th><th>Rate Plan</th><th>Act</th><th>churn<th>Net</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
   while($row = $result10->fetch_assoc()) {
   
       // echo "<tr> <td>".$row[""]."1</td> <td>".$row["dealer_code"]."</td> <td> ".$row["dealer_name"]."</td>  </tr>";
        echo "<tr> <td>".$row["report_date"]."</td> <td> ".$row["rate_plan"]."</td> <td>".$row["act"]."</td><td>".$row["churn"]."</td><td>".$row["net"]."</td>  </tr>";
                }
     ?>
```

Comment: and see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
<?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM stock WHERE amr_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $searchkey); // 's' specifies the variable type => 'string'

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$sum=0;
echo "<table id='customers'  border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' style='text-align:left;'><tr><th>Date</th><th>Rate Plan</th><th>Act</th><th>churn<th>Net</th></tr>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr> <td>".$row["report_date"]."</td> <td> ".$row["rate_plan"]."</td> <td>".$row["act"]."</td><td>".$row["churn"]."</td><td>".$row["net"]."</td>  </tr>";
    $sum+=$row['act'];
}
echo $sum;
```

this should be the approach to avoid sql injection vulnerability

Comment: This is a good answer, but without a proper explanation and without clearer question it will not be very useful for future readers

Comment: Yes this code is working and solved my problem, thank you so much! Have a great weekend to all!